# What is happening with this page?

Tags: support, security

I don't quite know where to begin with, how to pose this question or even if this is the correct site ...

Spoiler: Beware of the pop-up when clicking the link below.

I found by link on Google Search, and wound up on [this site](https://tyip.guillaumepanariello.com/questions/56690310/swiftui-dynamic-list-with-sections-does-not-layout-correctly).

It looks like Stack Overflow (in the Google search result title), yet it obviously is not (inappropriate ad in bottom right).

"Some" links on the right go to legitimate SO URLs, but they often show SO content embedded in a site with more "inappropriate" content.

What is happening here and is Stack Overflow interested in this?

Comment: Start by not clicking on non-SO or official docs links, so that they don't get pushed up the result list.